# How to send message from panel to page-mod's content script directly?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

If there is a code snippet in Firefox addon like following:

```
var pagemod = PageMod({
    include: ['*'],
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('content.js')]
});

panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  width: 322,
  height: 427,
  contentURL: data.url("main.html"),
  include:["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
  contentScriptFile: [data.url('panel.js')]  
});
```

I have found some example code in the Chrome extension. They use `window.parent.postMessage(message, "*")` to send message and use `window.addEventListener("message",function (e) {//do something}` to receive message.
How can I send message from "`panel.js`" to "`content.js`" directly in the Firefox addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of the solution is very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778772/how-to-implement-chrome-extension-s-chrome-tabs-sendmessage-api-in-firefox-addo/17783378#17783378):

1. Maintain a list of message ports for each tab.
2. Whenever you want to send a message, send a message to all listed ports.

The following code is used to maintain a list of ports:

```js
var ports = [];
var pagemod = PageMod({
    include: ['*'],
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('content.js')],
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        ports.push(worker.port);
        worker.on('detach', function() {
            var index = ports.indexOf(worker.port);
            if (index !== -1) ports.splice(index, 1);
        });
    }
});
```

Now, whenever you want to send a message from `panel.js`, just use:

```js
// panel.js
self.port.emit('message-to-tabs', 'example of message');
```

The message has to be handled in the main script, after creation of the panel:

```js
panel = require('sdk/panel').Panel({
    width: 322,
    height: 427,
    contentURL: data.url('main.html'),
    include: ['http://*/*', 'https://*/*'],
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('panel.js')]  
});
panel.port.on('message-to-tabs', function(message) {
    for (var i=0; i<ports.length; i++) {
        ports[i].emit('message-to-tab', message);
    }
});
```

In the tab's content script (content.js), you can listen to this event and handle it as follows:

```js
self.port.on('message-to-tab', function(message) {
    // Do something with message
});
```

Comment: Yes,I have tried this solution which send message to the active tab.But it can't work.So I want to ask for a solution which can send message to content script directly like the chrome version in the question.

Comment: @penkzhou The answer will work for the example you've provided. I don't see any Chrome-specific thing in your question, if you want to use `postMessage` in your content scripts, use `document.defaultView.postMessage('some data', '*')` and `document.defaultView.addEventListener('message', function(event) { /* do something with event.data */ });`.

Comment: I found something useful [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/communicating-with-other-scripts.html). Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `var index = ports.indexOf(worker.port);`, or is there a global `port` that I'm unaware of?

Comment: @RobW How can i send message from content script to main.js using the above method?

Comment: @vivek https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Communicating_With_Content_Scripts