# How to listen for messages in the main.js using "browser-action-jplib"

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script, browser-action

I read about the lib from [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778772/how-to-implement-chrome-extension-s-chrome-tabs-sendmessage-api-in-firefox-addo), which is pretty much exactly what I need.

I am creating a badge using his library:

```
var badge = require("browserAction").BrowserAction({
    default_icon:  data.url("images/icon19.png"),
    default_title: "MyAddon",
    default_popup: data.url("pages/popup.html")
});
```

The popup is going to contact the main via his [messaging protocol](https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib/blob/master/docs/messaging.md) and will be sending a callback function. Therefore I am opening the message channel in the *main.js*:

```
const { createMessageChannel } = require('messaging');
var options = {channelName:"PopUpMessageChannel", endAtPage: false};
var extension = createMessageChannel(options, badge.port);
extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message === 'test') {
        sendResponse("Test recieved");
    }
});
```

My question: What port do I need to use in `createMessageChannel(options, **HERE**)`?
 I always get the error `port is undefined`when I use `badge.port` or `self.port`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create the message channel yourself.

I've already added the `onMessage.addListener` and `sendMessage` methods to the [browser-action-jplib](https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib). Just read the documentation (generated using `cfx sdocs` from [docs/browser-action.md](https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib/blob/master/docs/browser-action.md)).

Use it as follows:

```js
const { data } = require("sdk/self");
var badge = require("browserAction").BrowserAction({
    default_icon:  data.url("images/icon19.png"),
    default_title: "MyAddon",
    default_popup: data.url("pages/popup.html")
});
badge.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message === "test") {
        sendResponse("Test recieved");
    }
});
```

Minimal JavaScript code in popup, for the sake of the example:

```js
extension.sendMessage("test", function(message) {
    document.body.textContent = message;
});
```