# what is the purpose tabid in chrome extension? {chrome.tabs.sendMessage(integer tabId, any message, function responseCallback)}

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, porting, firefox-addon-sdk

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(integer tabId, any message, function responseCallback)
```

In this what is the purpose of tab id? Is that required when I port to Firefox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` you can send some information to a content script. And with `tabId` you specifiy the tab you want so send the message to.

See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage for more info for chrome.

I don't know about Firefox though. Maybe this question helps: [how to implement Chrome extension 's chrome.tabs.sendMessage API in Firefox addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778772/how-to-implement-chrome-extension-s-chrome-tabs-sendmessage-api-in-firefox-addo)